# RunTimeError in Abstract method

Tags: java, javafx

I have made an interface and then implemented it. The interface exists in my first project. When I add first project to another second project it works well. If I modify that interface in first project and implement it again and run the second project it throws an abstract method error.

How to resolve this?

My first project interface mentioned below.

```
public interface LoginController extends Remote
{
    public boolean searchRequirements(String userName,String password)throws RemoteException,SQLException,ClassNotFoundException;

    public int getClientId(String userName,String password)throws RemoteException,SQLException,ClassNotFoundException;

    public boolean addNewLogin(String userName,String password,int client_id)throws RemoteException,SQLException,ClassNotFoundException;

    public ArrayList<String> getAllLogins()throws RemoteException,SQLException,ClassNotFoundException;
}
```

This is my implemented class.

```
public class LoginControllerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements LoginController{

private static final LoginDBAccess LOGIN_DBACCESS=new LoginDBAccess();

public LoginControllerImpl()throws RemoteException{

}

@Override
public boolean searchRequirements(String userName, String password) throws RemoteException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    return LOGIN_DBACCESS.searchRequirements(userName, password);
}

@Override
public int getClientId(String userName, String password) throws RemoteException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    return LOGIN_DBACCESS.getClientId(userName, password);
}

@Override
public boolean addNewLogin(String userName, String password, int client_id) throws RemoteException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    return LOGIN_DBACCESS.addNewLogin(userName, password, client_id);
}

@Override
public ArrayList<String> getAllLogins()throws RemoteException,SQLException,ClassNotFoundException{

    return LOGIN_DBACCESS.getAllLogins();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you mention what was the change done and how are you calling this method?

Answer (score 2):

From the java documentation for [`AbstractMethodError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html):

> Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled.

Your likely scenario is that, as the documentation says, your class must have changed at runtime. Which also means you haven't yet implemented the method you're trying to invoke; it is still abstract. Try defining the method of whatever class you're using.

Specifically to your situation, it looks like `getAllLogins()` of class `LoginControllerImpl` is not implemented. Try implementing it.

Comment: thanks! but i implement it.It's not work still.I will show the implemented class

Comment: Look to see if `getAllLogins()` is defined in `LoginDBAccess`. That is the other option.

Comment: feel free to accept the answer, if it helped answer your question.